# Extracting columns added during the last minute from the csv file

Tags: cron

I wrote a script that runs sql * loader every minute to drop the data from the csv file into the database.  However, it needs this script to extract data from the last minute csv file, and not read the entire file every time.  The csv file is structured in such a way that the first place is a timestamp in the format yyyy-mm-dd HH: mm: ss I had an idea to extract this data from the last minute, save it to another file and pass this file to sql * loader.  Anyone have an idea how to write it?

Example input file (as per OP)

```
2022-02-26 11:11:05;column1;columm2;column3
```

Comment: Please provide example of your input file

Comment: The file has 4 columns and the separator is ; For example: 2022-02-26 11:11:05;column1;columm2;column3